# Values to Columns and Rows

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I am using this script in Google Sheets to extract data from [coinmarketcap api](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/). I added a loop (`coins.forEach`) to get all the data of the coins I want in just one call to the API (limited credits). But after each loop/coin, it keeps going down in the column and I would like to use a new column for each coin.

How can I do this without calling the function (and the API) again for each coin? I hope I made myself clear, I can't remember where I've got the original script.

```js
function cmc(){
  var response = CMCFetch();
  if (response.status === true) { response.data = response.datos; 
      }  
  return response.data;}

function xCMCFetch() {
  
    var uri = "https://sandbox-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

      cache     = CacheService.getScriptCache(),
      response  = { status: true, name: "Unknown", USD: 0, BTC: 0, datos: [], error:null },
      obj_array = null;
      obj_array = JSON.parse(cache.get('firstX'));
  if (obj_array === null ) 
  { try { 
    obj_array = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(uri).getContentText());  
    cache.put('firstX', JSON.stringify(obj_array), 20); }   // ** cache for 20 sec
    catch (e) { response.status = false; response.error = e }  }   
   
  var coins = ["btc","eth","ltc","bch"]; 
  
  if (response.status === true) { 
    coins.forEach(function(symb){
   for (r in obj_array.data){
      if (obj_array.data[r].symbol == symb.toUpperCase()) { 
        response.datos.push(
          obj_array.data[r].total_supply,          
          obj_array.data[r].cmc_rank,
          obj_array.data[r].quote.USD.market_cap,
          obj_array.data[r].quote.USD.volume_24h,
          parseFloat(obj_array.data[r].quote.USD.percent_change_7d), 
          parseFloat(obj_array.data[r].quote.USD.percent_change_24h), 
          parseFloat(obj_array.data[r].quote.USD.percent_change_1h),
          obj_array.data[r].quote.USD.price
           );
        break;  }   } })}
  return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem lies `for (r in obj_array.data)`. 
This means that you are iterating through each object's properties. 
So you can't call `obj_array.data[r].symbol`. 
Replace it with `for (int r = 0; r < obj_array.data.length; r++)`

Comment: I replaced `for (r in obj_array.data)` with `for (int r = 0; r < obj_array.data.length; r++) {` and shows error "Missing ; after for-loop initializer - line 27"
I mean, the code works fine, I just want to separate the data into different rows AND columns, not just one long column